# Make select box to be selected based on value from database

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a select box with values generated from database. How can I make it to be selected on the value which is stored in the database?

```
<select name="city" class="form-control">   
<?php foreach($records->result_array() as $row) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row['id_city']?>"> 
    <?=$row['city']?>, <?=$row['country']?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to solve with a different example

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
 $db = mysql_select_db("exampleTest",$con);
 $get=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM example ORDER BY id ASC");
$option = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form>
 <select> 
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```